# Ajax call to web service - success in method but forbids data access

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services

I am trying to call a web service from an ajax jquery. It is successfully entering the success method but unfortunately a 403 error is being triggered and thus won't allow me to access the data.

This is my code:

```
    try {
    $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: urlAddress,
  data: dataa,
  contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",

  success: function(Msg) {
 //   $("#Result").text(msg.d);
    alert("ok");
    alert("hi "+Msg.responseText + " How are you?");
  },

  error: function(request, status, error) {
      alert("Error "+request.statusText.toString()); 
      alert("ERROR");
  }
});
    }
    catch (e)
    {}
```

Msg.ResponseText comes back "undefined"

From Live Http Headers I get the following:

> Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
>   Accept-Charset:
>   ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
>   Keep-Alive: 115 Connection: keep-alive
>   Origin: null
>   Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
>
> HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 
>   Content-Length:1758 
>   Content-Type: text/html 
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0 
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET 
>   Date: Tue, 27 Jul 2010 10:59:04 GMT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smells like `urlAddress` is not located on the same domain you're running that script.

That would breach the `same origin policy` and therefore, fail.

If I'm wrong here with that assumption, your're webservice might require a login (username+password) which you might missing to pass through `.ajax()`.

Comment: I tried accessing the web service using Soap and there were no problems...so I'm not sure